# AWS: What can I use to run periodic tasks on RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

In specific RDS column as a date, I keep the information when user's trials end.

I'm going to check everyday these dates in database and when less the few days lefts to the end of trial, I want send an email message (with SES).

How can I run a periodic tasks in AWS to check database? I know that I can use:

- Lambda
- EC2 (or Elastic Beanstalk)

Is there any other solution which I've missed?

Comment: You will only get opinions here for this type of question, and stack is not the best place for this. Also, you already have best solution imho, Lambda scheduled with Cloudwatch.

Comment: You didn't mention which kind of RDS.  RDS Aurora for MySQL has a built-in event scheduler and can spawn Lambda functions from inside RDS itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long does it take to run your check? If it takes less than 300 sec and is well within the limits of Lambda ([AWS Lambda Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)), then schedule tasks with Lambda: [Schedule Expressions Using Rate or Cron](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)

Otherwise, the best option is to use: [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/details/). Very easy to schedule and run your custom script periodically. It charges at least one hour of instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) for this. This suits better if the job is heavy and takes more time to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Go with lamda [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)

You can create a Lambda function and direct AWS Lambda to execute it on a regular schedule. You can specify a fixed rate (for example, execute a Lambda function every hour or 15 minutes), or you can specify a Cron expression.