# How to Schedule a job in AWS RDS postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have one AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance, is there any way we can schedule a job that will call any PostgreSQL method as we do in SQL server to call procedure/method from job?

Comment: cloudwatch scheduler and lambda?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323261/aws-what-can-i-use-to-run-periodic-tasks-on-rds